# How to get multiselect checkbox data in update action and save it in junction table

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I have two models (Video, Category). In my video form i am fetching the categories (from Category model) and show them as checkboxes (note that: there is no categories field inside video table). each video can have single or multiple categories. I need to save the video categories (which are to be selected inside video form) inside a junction table (video_categories). I will save the categories using afterSave() inside Video model.
My main problem is that how can i fetch my checked categories from video form inside updateAction() of VideoController, and assign them to some public member (of Video model) and then use that member in afterSave() to save the categories inside that junction table (video_categories).
*One more thing is that I want to save the categories inside updateAction() only. In createAction() i am saving just the video file. all other details about video needs to be saved inside updateAction().*

This is how I displayed Categories inside video form.

```
<ul class="catgss_list">
<?php 
$category = common\models\Category::find()->all(); 
foreach($category as $cat):
?>
<li>
    <div class="chekbox-lg">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="<?php echo $cat->id ?>">
            <b class="checkmark"></b>
            <span><?= $cat->category_name ?></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

this is how my form looks like https://ibb.co/tpZXrVw

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem. what I did is written below:-
my Video model

```
public $categories;// i declare a public attribute. 
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    $this->deleteExistingCategories();
    if (isset($_POST['Video']['categories'])) {
        $this->saveVideoCategories($_POST['Video']['categories']);
    }
}

public function deleteExistingCategories() {
    VideoCategory::deleteAll(['video_id' => $this->video_id]);
}

public function saveVideoCategories($categoriesList) {
  foreach ($categoriesList as $category) {
      $videoCategory = new VideoCategory();
      $videoCategory->video_id = $this->video_id;
      $videoCategory->category_id = $category;
      $videoCategory->save();
  }
}
```

my video form code

```
<ul class="catgss_list">
<?php
$checkedCategories = VideoCategory::findAll(['video_id' => $model->video_id]);
if (isset($checkedCategories)) {
    foreach ($checkedCategories as $selectedCategory) {
        $savedCategories[] = $selectedCategory->category_id;
    }
}
$category = Category::find()->all();
foreach ($category as $cat):
?>
<li>
    <div class="chekbox-lg">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Video[categories][]" value="<?php echo $cat->id ?>" 
            <?php
            if (isset($savedCategories)) {
                $isCategory = in_array($cat->id, $savedCategories);
                if (isset($isCategory) && $isCategory == true) {
                    echo "checked";
                }
            }
            ?>
                   >
            <b class="checkmark"></b>
            <span><?php echo $cat->category_name ?></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```